# Automatically post file from webserver

Tags: php, file, post

I'm trying to make a script that sends a file from my server to another server via POST method.
The HTML may look like this:

```
<form action="https://anotherserver/receive.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

With this part, I can send a file from my computer to another server. But the script should send the file from my webserver, if a condition is true. For example, I create a file on my website, I hit "OK" and the file is automatically sent to the external webserver.
Is it possible such a method? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will post a file to another server:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://anotherserver/receive.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $post = array(
        "file"=>"/path/to/myfile.jpg",
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Adapted from: http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html